# Not able to load new folders to github

Tags: c#, github

I have created A Github repository and uploaded the solution/projects initially.  I have since then added some files and folders to one of the projects.  I have committed the project, but I am unable to see the new files/folders within my repository.

Can someone please point me into the direction to get these files/folders uploaded?

Thank you in advance.],

Comment: Have you commited to your local or your remote repository ? You normally have to push the commits you have made to your remote repository

Comment: You'll have to use: `git push`. This may help: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are not using any third party tool for Git.

Git will not track new files you add to repository until you explicitly tell it too using Git command-line tool. Use the following commands:

```
git add nameOfFile
```

`git status` You should see the added file(s).

```
git commit -m "Comment about the commit"
```

`git push` This will push to the repository.